# Console log message fires despite of the condition statement - Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Purpose of my code, is to fire `fetchNumbers()` (that fetches numbers from API) when a user scrolls bottom of the page, some kind of infinite scroll. I'm having issue with condition inside axios promise (then), because it fires two `console.log` outputs at the same time. Seems like condition is ignored at all.

Method i'm using:

```
methods: {
fetchNumbers (type = 'default', offset = 0, limit = 0) {
  return axios.get(globalConfig.NUMBERS_URL)
    .then((resp) => {
       if (type === 'infinite') {
         console.log('infinite fired')
       } else {
         console.log('default fired')
       }
    })
}
```

Mounted function (where i suspect the issue):

```
mounted () {
  window.onscroll = () => {
    let bottomOfWindow = document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight > document.documentElement.offsetHeight - 1
    if (bottomOfWindow) {
      this.fetchNumbers('infinite')
    }
  }
}
```

When i reload the page, or enter it, i'm getting 2 console outputs at the same time:

`default fired`
`infinite fired`

Sometimes the order is reversed.

**UPDATE.**

Methods that calling `fetchNumbers()`

```
async created () {
  await this.fetchNumbers()
}

showCats (bool) {
  this.showCategories = bool

  if (!bool) {
    this.category = [1]
  } else {
    this.category = []
  }
  this.isActive = true
  this.fetchNumbers()
}
```

**UPDATE 2.**

Found the culprit - would post it in an answer.

**UPDATE 3.**

Issue is indeed with `onscroll` function. I have 3 pages in my APP: main page, numbers page, contact page. If i go to the numbers page (where onscroll function is mounted), then go to main or contact page, then this `onscroll` function is still attached and when i reach the bottom - it fires my api call, even if it's not the numbers page. Is it possible to limit this function only to numbers page?

Comment: Try logging when your component is mounted. How many times does that happen? You should be removing the event handler when your component is unmounted / destroyed

Comment: Tried to debug using chrome tool, set the breakpoints on these 2 problem places where it checks for the type infinite and default. On the page reload it checks the first condtion (`type === 'infinite') and somehow it passes, that's why i'm getting console log output infinite fired, then it checks a first condition again! and didn't pass as expected, then running the default statement. It does check the first condition twice. Why?

Comment: Also, there's absolutely no code shown which would trigger the "default" type. What is calling your method with no / default arguments?

Comment: Updated the answer. `showCats` is called only on a click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to disable `onscroll` listener on `destroy`:

```
destroyed () {
  window.onscroll = null
}
```

So when i visit the main or contact page, that listener won't be attached.

Also i had to move `onscroll` listener from `mounted` to `created`, because when it was in `mounted ()` it was firing twice:

```
created () {
  window.onscroll = () => {
    let bottomOfWindow = document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight > document.documentElement.offsetHeight - 1
    if (bottomOfWindow) {
      this.isActive = true
      this.fetchNumbers('infinite', counter++ * this.limit)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fetchNumbers is most definetly called twice.
Try log every context as type.

```
fetchNumbers (type = 'default', offset = 0, limit = 0) {
   return axios.get(globalConfig.NUMBERS_URL)
     .then((resp) => {
       if (type === 'infinite') {
         console.log(type,'infinite fired');    //this will always print 'infinite', 'inifinite fired'
       } else {
         console.log(type,'default fired');     //this will print the caller's name and 'default fired'
         type = 'default';                      //after logging reset type to 'default' to continue the execution
       }
     })
}

async created () {
  await this.fetchNumbers('created');
}

showCats (bool) {
  this.showCategories = bool

   if (!bool) {
     this.category = [1];
   } else {
     this.category = [];
   }
   this.isActive = true
   this.fetchNumbers('showCats');
}
```

Either created or showCats is being fired for some reason at the same time as window.onscroll. The randomly changing order suggests a race condition between the two methods.

UPDATE

This should work, provided you nested the desired page in a div with id="number_page_div_id" (you may probably have to adjust that elements height and position):

```
created () {
  let element = getElementById('numbers_page_div_id');
  element.onscroll = () => {        
    let bottomOfWindow = element.scrollTop + window.innerHeight > element.offsetHeight - 1;
    if (bottomOfWindow) {
      this.fetchNumbers('infinite')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `let bottomOfWindow = document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight > document.documentElement.offsetHeight - 1` this is true when i'm not at the bottom of the page somehow. It's firing my function with infinite type. Does `mounted ()` share it contents between all components? Because my console log fires even if i go to another pages, after visiting the one with mounted function.

Comment: I think the reason is that mounted() checks the scrollTop of the document element, that means it will be triggered in any page. If you want it to work on only one page, you should put that page inside a div with overflow-x: scroll or auto and check that div's scrollTop.

Comment: Updated again, so you could bind the onScroll event on a specified element instead of the whole window.

Answer (score -1):

you may approach separate condition instead of if/else e.g.

```
.then((resp) => {
       if (type === 'infinite') {
         console.log('infinite fired')
       }
       if (type === 'default '){
         console.log('default fired')
       }
    })
```

Comment: how would that help?

Comment: it's kind of simple approach with explicit checking. like both are totally independent. Mounted()  gets called  when data changed details [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) . I this case, this function get call may be twice ..

Comment: i suspect it runs twice, but explicit checking didn't help.